# Java Applet File Permission Errors

Tags: java, javascript, security, exception, applet

This exception occurs  when I want to access a PDF file and print it:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission write)

To access file and print is all within one function and I am using JS/PHP button to access this applet function. The applet and JS/PHP work communicating between each other. There was a read `fileDFpermissionexception` before but I figured I can use the File class method `setReadable(true);` and that worked.

Unfortunately `setWritable(true)` does not. I have also included a policy file and signed my jar, so I am not sure whats going on here. I have read little so far but perhaps this code can help me?:

```
java.security.PrivilegedAction() { public Object run() {
```

Not even sure what it does so any help with this question would be great

Answer (score 1):

You're looking into right direction - actions that requier an approval from `SecurityManager` (like file operations) should be executed from PrivilegedAction in applets. Then if all the code is trusted (signed and certificate installed in browser), that would work.

Comment: I thought that `PrivilegedAction()` was used by trusted code to say to the `SecurityManager` "even if I'm being invoked by untrused code, this bit right here is still OK to do".